# -Wstrict-aliasing=3 throws warning where -Wstrict-aliasing=1 does not

Tags: c, gcc, gcc-warning

Using GCC 5.4.0.

The example is trivial. The code violates the strict aliasing rule on two occasions.

> "dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules"

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main() {
    uint8_t buffer[100]; // line 1
    uint32_t test = *((uint32_t*)(&buffer[10]));  // line 2
    uint32_t* pTest2 = (uint32_t*)(&buffer[10]);  // line 3
    test = *pTest2;  // line 4
}
```

- -Wstrict-aliasing=3 warns about line 2 only
- -Wstrict-aliasing=2 warns about line 2 and 3
- -Wstrict-aliasing=1 **throws no warning at all**

From the [GCC documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html):

> Level 1: Most aggressive, quick, least accurate. Possibly useful when higher levels do not warn but -fstrict-aliasing still breaks the code, as it has very few false negatives. However, it has many false positives. **Warns for all pointer conversions between possibly incompatible types, even if never dereferenced.** Runs in the front end only.

Now I am unsure about how reliable -Wstrict-aliasing=1 actually is. Is this an issue with GCC 5.4.0?

Comment: I always found that setting buggy as can be. `-fno-strict-aliasing` is the way to go. Tells the UB to get lost, the C standard be damned.

Comment: "quick", "least accurate", "front end only".  See no reason to consider this a bug. Docs on level 2 say: "few false negatives (but possibly more than level 1)", so false negatives seem to be expected on level 1 too.

Comment: @xaizek: True. But since "line 2" is such an obvious case, I would really not have expected a false negative there. But I don't pretend to know much about compiler construction, there are probably "reasons" why it is the way it is.

Comment: I've tried your code at compiler explorer and GCC stops producing warnings at 7.2 onwards even after removing UB related to `buffer` not being initialized. Warnings appear if `uint8_t` is changed to `float`, which reminded me that `unsigned char` is allowed to alias anything and code for `-Wstrict-aliasing=1` just compares alias sets of types (on trunk at least). However, I'm not sure this is a valid explanation. There are multiple bug tickets related to strict aliasing, but maybe it's warranted to open another one asking for clarification about your example.